# How to calculate the complexity of this function?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, complexity-theory

I'm wondering what is the time-complexity of the inner for-loop, is it sqrt(n) or log(n)?

```c
void foo(int n)
{
 for (int i=0; i<n*n; ++i)
     for (int j=1; j*j<n; j*=2)
         printf("Hello there!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

j in inner for loop will take values 1,2,4,...2^t

Also according to constraint given,
2^2t = n

So, t = (1/2)logn

Therefore the inner loop should have Time Complexity O(log(n))

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think the inner for-loop has complexity O(sqrt(n)). To make it O(log(n)), the inner for loop should be something like this:</strike>

### EDIT

It should be O(log(n)).

Comment: It's O( log(sqrt(n)) ) which is the same as O(log(n)) because `log(sqrt(n)) = log(n) / 2`.